# Align axislabel in nvd3

Tags: nvd3.js

I want to align the axis label for X axis and Yaxis in NVD3.js. I have attached a fiddle link. For example, I want the X axis label 'Time (ms)' to move closely to X-axis from its current position. Please advise on achieving this and also please let me know if there are any options to align.

jsfiddle.net/balajipalamadai/d2Dj6/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this you'll need to select the axis text and change x, y, dx, dy, text-anchor attributes accordingly, for example:

```
 d3.select(".nv-axislabel")
    .attr("dy", -5)
```

Demo example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4A6L8/1/).

Comment: thanks for the useful tip it did the job is there any way so that I can align the axis label, left , middle or right?

Comment: You will need to change x, dx or text-anchor attributes in order to make a horizontal alignment.